# Hello World Application in XCode 5.0.2

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I was trying to build my first application in xcode 5.0.2 i've put just one label on my xib file and i clicked Build and Run button, i got the following error.

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

and the segment of code in main is highlighted as green.

```
@autoreleasepool {
    return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
}
```

I have coded nothing actually just put a label inside of the xib file.

Comment: What do you mean by "_i clicked to get it simulated_"?

Comment: Click to Simulation button :)

Comment: What do you mean by "Click to Simulation button "?

Comment: Build and Run Button.

Comment: @Mutawe So you're running this in the simulator? Can you update the question with the full error message, please?

Comment: Which application did u choose when you creating your project? there is no xib in default, u probably added this xib class ? maybe you should add some breakpoints.

Comment: I tried to avoid storyboard in xcode 5.0.2 then i tried to live with it, since i decided to do it, i learned and then i solved the problem. thanks guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try following [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/25561/learn-to-code-ios-apps-3-your-first-app)  tutorial. That should teach you how to code your first app.

Answer (score 4):

@Nothingbutageek, welcome to Stackoverflow. I see you are starting to program with ios. To be able to cope with the upcoming errors also in future it is good to know how to debug.

I found this tutorial while trying to figure out the exception you got.

Tutorial about crashes:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1

Also, I found the exception you have is the most general one, you can have on IOS programming and the real cause is maybe on the next line of the exception text if there is any. If not, take that tutorial and look for your self what is there.

If there is that another exception, post it here and we can tell more..